# Inheritance in nested namespaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, scope, javascript-namespaces

I want to setup nested namespaces to organize my code. I am trying to follow the plugin-like structure described in [this article](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/). The problem is I don't understand how to access `this.error_msg` in my example. Have I set this up correctly? Would I have to use jQuery `.extend` or `.prototype` to access `this.error_msg`?

```
(function(TC, $, undefined){

    TC.ajax = function() {
        this.error_msg = 'default error...';         
    };

    TC.ajax.run = function(){
        //do stuff...
        TC.ajax.handle_error();
    };

    TC.ajax.handle_error = function(){
        alert(this.error_msg);
    };        

}(window.TC = window.TC || {}, jQuery));

// Test it
TC.ajax.run();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g99yt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
(function ($, TC, undefined) {

    TC.nestedNamespace = TC.nestedNamespace || {};

    //add a public function to our new namespace 
    TC.nestedNamespace.test = function () {        
       console.log("Winning!");    
    };

}(jQuery, window.TC = window.TC || {}));

TC.nestedNamespace.test();
```

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/8e4Cm/). I found this method in the comments of a [related article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/my-current-javascript-design-pattern/).

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to remember is that each time you use `function()`, you are creating a new scope. So you can see that in your `TC.ajax.handle_error` method that `this.error_msg` is undefined because you haven't defined it in that scope. One thing you can do is prototype to make sure those methods relate back to your ajax object and declare a new instance of the object, and then call your methods on that. see below :

```
(function(TC, $, undefined){

    TC.ajax = function() {
        this.error_msg = 'default error...';         
    };

    TC.ajax.prototype.run = function(){
        //do stuff...
        this.handle_error.call(this);
    };

    TC.ajax.prototype.handle_error = function(){
        alert(this.error_msg);
    };        

}(window.TC = window.TC || {}, jQuery));

// Test it
 var ajaxInstance = new TC.ajax();

ajaxInstance.run();
```

and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mujWP/)

you do have other options like keeping a locally global variable like @kta does, or by setting your scope through the `call` function, but that doesn't really apply well to your structure.

Comment: This maintains scope well unlike the other solutions. It sucks to add the step of having to create an instance, but I understand why that is required.

Comment: glad I could help. it's probably a good idea to get into the practice of creating instances if you plan on getting into more indepth object oriented javascript

Answer (score 2):

I think your code must look something like this:

```
(function(TC, $, undefined){
    _this = this;
    TC.ajax = function() {
        _this.error_msg = 'default error...';         
    };

    TC.ajax.run = function(){
        //do stuff...
        TC.ajax.handle_error();
    };

    TC.ajax.handle_error = function(){
        alert(_this.error_msg);
    };        

}(window.TC = window.TC || {}, jQuery));

// Test it
TC.ajax.run();
```

Comment: This works but I am trying to avoid `error_msg` being global (under TC) in scope. I want it only accessible from TC.ajax and functions nested below that. So when I wrote `this.error_msg` what I meant was `TC.ajax.error_msg`. So far it looks like I'd need to use prototype for this, as described by Evan... Unless you know another way?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a common problem, it's not immediately clear what `this` refers to. So to explain:

```
TC.ajax.handle_error = function(){
    alert(this.error_msg);
};
```

The `this` in the `TC.ajax.handle_error` function refers to the function and not your `TC` object.
So just save the reference to `TC` so you can refer to it later:

```
var _this = this;

...
_this.error_msg = 'default error....';
...

TC.ajax.handle_error = function(){
     alert(_this.error_msg);
 };
```

Comment: Hmmm, but I am trying to reference TC.ajax.error_msg, not TC.error_msg. How would this apply to that scope?

Comment: @Justin Sorry I'll clarify the answer, `TC` has `error_message` as a property, so having that reference to `TC` allows you to access `TC.error_msg`.

Answer (score 0):

If `TC.ajax` is supposed to be a constructor, then `run()` and `handle_error()` need to be added to a prototype.

But you could do something like

```
TC.ajax = {};    
TC.ajax.error_msg = 'default error...';
```

In your case `error_msg` will be assigned to `this` as soon as you call `TC.ajax()`, which never happens. And even then, `this` would refer to `TC`. And when `TC.ajax.handle_error()`is called, `this` refers to `TC.ajax`.